# ArcGIS Online won't display weather widgets

Tags: arcgis-online, popup

Trying to add a custom pop-up using real time weather underground personal weather station data feeds like:
https://www.wunderground.com/personal-weather-station/dashboard?ID=KFLBUSHN3

When I add these in a data field or as a url link via an html file it works fine in ArcGIS Desktop. They want a shared ArcGIS Online app instead. Doesn't seem to work in there. i can get the url in a pop-up, but no display of the data feed happens..

Comment: you need to sign up and use the api key here is how to set it up https://github.com/Esri/dashboard-samples/tree/master/weatherWidget